# Is it good practice to use counters?

Tags: performance, algorithm, for-loop, counter, julia

Here are two alternative codes (coded in Julia) that do essentially the same thing.

```
counter = 0
for i = myArray
    counter = counter + 1
    Do1(i)
    Do2(counter)
end
```

and

```
for counter = 1:length(myArray)
    i = myArray[counter]
    Do1(i)
    Do2(j)
end
```

What is the good practice? Which code is faster? Which code consumes less memory? Which code is less error prone? Why?

Comment: please define the "best"

Comment: @akonsu Thank for your comment. I edited my question. The answer might well be along the lines of "it doesn't change much! Pick the one that is more intuitive to you" or along the lines of "if the loop is the array is very long, it might be preferable to use ..."

Comment: I would say they are the same. Although, I do not know what these expressions mean exactly because I do not know what language this is. As you know, iterating over an array takes linear time and constant memory. No matter how you implement the loop.

Comment: and you mean `i = myArray[j]` perhaps.

Comment: I hoped the answer would be general enough so that the code doesn't matter. With a tiny update (fixing the other issue you mentioned) it is now coded in Julia.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In julia, you can test this very easily:

```
function indexing(A)
    si = 0
    sA = zero(eltype(A))
    for i = 1:length(A)
        sA += A[i]
        si += i
    end
    si, sA
end

function counter(A)
    si = 0
    sA = zero(eltype(A))
    i = 0
    for a in A
        sA += a
        si += (i += 1)
    end
    si, sA
end

function enumrt(A)
    si = 0
    sA = zero(eltype(A))
    for (i, a) in enumerate(A)
        sA += a
        si += i
    end
    si, sA
end

A = rand(Float32, 10^8)
# Compile all the functions, including those needed to time things
indexing(A)
counter(A)
enumrt(A)
@time 1+1

# Test the timing
@time indexing(A)
@time counter(A)
@time enumrt(A)
```

Output:

```
elapsed time: 4.61e-6 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.12948093 seconds (144 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.191082557 seconds (144 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.331076493 seconds (160 bytes allocated)
```

If you add `@inbounds` annotations before every loop, then you get this:

```
elapsed time: 4.632e-6 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.12512546 seconds (144 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.12340103 seconds (144 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.323285599 seconds (160 bytes allocated)
```

So the difference between the first two is really just the effectiveness of automatic bounds-checking removal. Finally, if you really want to dive into the details, you can inspect the generated machine code using `@code_native indexing(A)`, or use `@code_llvm` to inspect the LLVM IR (internal representation).

However, in some cases readability may be more important, and so the `enumerate` approach is one I use often (but not in truly performance-critical code).

Comment: Interesting, it's quite unfortunate that `enumerate` ends up being dramatically slower, despite being part of the base library.

Comment: I think there's a reasonable chance that this would be fixed (or at least improved) by https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9182, but I haven't had time to test.

Comment: This is now greatly improved on the unstable 0.4 after the [redesign of tuples and tuple types](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/10380).  I am no longer seeing any measurable overhead with `enumerate`!  (Timings with `@inbounds`: 0.13/0.12/0.13).

Comment: Can confirm the difference is now negligible. Does this mean we can freely use enumerate??

Answer (score 7):

I don't actually know much about Julia, but the pattern is common enough that most (sane) languages have a built-in function to help you deal with such an indecision.  In both Python and Julia, it's called [`enumerate`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.enumerate):

> Return an iterator that yields `(i, x)` where `i` is an index starting at 1, and `x` is the ith value from the given iterator. It’s useful when you need not only the values `x` over which you are iterating, but also the index `i` of the iterations.

For your example, it would look like:

```
for (j, i) in enumerate(myArray)
    Do1(i)
    Do2(j)
end
```

Answer (score -7):

For a compiled language (e.g. C), I'd expect a decent/modern compiler to be able to convert both into the same executable code; so the only difference is readability/maintainability.

For a dynamic language (e.g. Julia), I'd expect minor differences in source code are dwarfed by the inefficiencies of the language and its run-time; so the only difference that matters is readability/maintainability.

For readability/maintainability; the latter seems cleaner to me.

Comment: In most cases, there _are no inefficiencies_ in julia's runtime: julia is a JIT-compiled language, and reduces to efficient machine code. So this answer makes no sense.

Comment: @tholy: Because you can do additional work at run-time (e.g. the JIT compiling) and that additional work won't add additional overhead; because all work costs nothing??

Comment: @Brendan, Julia code is typically about as fast as C code – at worst, it should not be more than 2x slower. Philosophically, the language rejects the idea that "minor differences in source code are dwarfed by the inefficiencies of the language and its run-time" – there is no longer any technical reason for dynamic languages to be so much slower than static ones. JIT compiling isn't free, but it's a one-time cost and generally not a big one – especially in a language designed to make JIT straightforward. It is also possible to pre-compile Julia code and avoid runtime JIT costs altogether.